# HTMLUnit error: Attempted to refresh a page using an ImmediateRefreshHandler which

Tags: htmlunit

For several days I'm facing an odd error with HTMLUnit - all page loads fail with following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Refresh to https://acme.com:11111/x/y/z aborted by HtmlUnit: Attempted to refresh a page using an ImmediateRefreshHandler which could have caused an OutOfMemoryError Please use WaitingRefreshHandler or ThreadedRefreshHandler instead.
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ImmediateRefreshHandler.handleRefresh(ImmediateRefreshHandler.java:56)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeRefreshIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1276)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:216)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:440)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
    ...
```

Well ... the error message is descriptive enough and I guess I can make the WebClient instances use WaitingRefreshHandler or ThreadedRefreshHandler.

However:

- these tests run against 4 different product releases and this issue
  occurs only on one of them.
- they run for about 3 years now and this
  issue appeared only recently.

Based on that - most probably the reason is in the target system but the error does not provide any further details what happened and why. Does anyone have an idea what is the root cause of this issue?

Note: I'm using htmlunit 2.9.

Comment: Change the refresh handler, use ThreadedRefreshHandler or create custom handler to fix the issue . HtmlUnit use Immdiate as default handler. I will suggest custom handler

Comment: Yep - this fixes the issue. I just don't understand the root cause. Like mentioned - the same coding is running against several releases and fails only on one of them.